# Solve $y''-y'-6y=e^{3t}+5$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems, inverse-laplace

> Solve the following initial value problem $$y'' - y' - 6y = e^{3t} + 5, \quad y(0) = 0, \quad y'(0) = 0 $$

---

I used the Laplace transform and got

$$ Y(s) \left(s^2-s-6\right)=\dfrac 1{s-3}+\dfrac 5s $$

then brought it to the other side

$$Y(s)=\dfrac 1{(s-3)(s^2-s-6)}+\dfrac 5{s(s^2-s-6)}$$

Taking user577215664's advice, I got

$$s^2−s−6=(s+2)(s−3)$$

so i split it into partial fractions

$$\dfrac A{(s-3)}+\dfrac B{(s-3)^2}+\dfrac C{(s+2)}$$ and solving it i got
in part A
$$ A=-\dfrac1{17}, \qquad B = C = \dfrac1{17} $$
and in part b
i got
$$ B=1\dfrac4{6}, \qquad A = C = -\dfrac5{6} $$
so end up having
$$-\dfrac1{17(s-3)}+\dfrac1{17(s-3)^2}+\dfrac1{17(s+2)}+-\dfrac5{6(s)}+\dfrac{10}{6(s-3)}+-\dfrac5{6(s+2)}$$

$$\dfrac1{17}e^{3t}+\dfrac1{17}te^{3t}+\dfrac1{17}e^{-2t}+-\dfrac5{6}+\dfrac{10}{6}e^{3t}+-\dfrac5{6}e^{-2t}$$
which can be simplified to
$$\dfrac{82}{51}e^{3t}+\dfrac{79}{102}e^{-2t}+\dfrac1{17}te^{3t}+\dfrac5{6}$$
is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Wish: What are the ICs?

Comment: The Laplace transform works best when you have some initial conditions, which is not the case here. Read in a standard differential equations text what to do when one of the solutons of the complementary equation (i.e. with the right side replaced by 0) appears on the right side.

Comment: There shouldn't be any lower-case $y$'s in the Laplace transform.

Comment: Note that $s^2-s-6=(s+2)(s-3)$ then decompose into simple fractions and take inverse Laplace Transform

Comment: It's not right.  First, you need to get rid of the lower-case $y$'s.     Then, what you have done is not "partial fractions."   The result of partial fractions is a sum, not a product.  It is not a rule that "the inverse transform of the product is product of the inverse transforms.

Comment: i honestly didn't notice the lower case y till now and thought you were talking bout the y in the qustion

Comment: Echoing other commenters to say:
1. That is not correct partial fraction decomposition, you may want to read up on how we find partial fractions.
2. We need "initial conditions", i.e. what $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ are. The Laplace transforms of derivatives include these.
You may want to do some more studying into second order differential equations to understand how they interact, especially **general vs specific** solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit with the ICs! You're almost there, it's just the partial fractions that are the problem now. Remember:
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{F(s)G(s)\}{\neq}f(t)g(t)$$

Comment: This can be done with elementary means, no Laplace

Comment: The result is $\frac{1}{150} e^{-2 t} \left(30 e^{5 t} t-125 e^{2 t}+44 e^{5 t}+81\right)$      `DSolve[{y''[t] - y'[t] - 6*y[t] == Exp[3 t] + 5, y[0] == 0, 
  y'[0] == 0}, y[t], t]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go to try to follow in your steps :

- We goal is to find the solution for the problem $y''-y'-6y=e^{3t}+5$ with $y(0)=y'(0)=0$.
- Laplace transform $L$ over the differential equation return a algebraic equation
  $$L(y''-y'-6y)=L(e^{3t}+5)$$
  by linearity and using the fact $y(0)=y'(0)=0$.
  Then,
  $$(S^{2}-S-6)L(y(t))=\frac{5}{S}+\frac{1}{S-3}$$
- Then, partial fraction descomposition give
  $$L(y(t))=\frac{3(2S-5)}{S(S-3)^{2}(S+2)}=\frac{1/5}{(S-3)^{2}}+\frac{22/75}{(S-3)}+\frac{-5/6}{S}+\frac{27/50}{(S+2)}$$
- Using the fact $L^{-1}(L(y(t))(s)=y(t)$, then
  $$y(t)=L^{-1}\left(\frac{1/5}{(S-3)^{2}}+\frac{22/75}{(S-3)}+\frac{-5/6}{S}+\frac{27/50}{(S+2)} \right),$$
  againg by linearity and using the known Laplace transforms, then we come to the *particular solution* for the problem given
  $$y(t)=\frac{22}{75}e^{3t}+\frac{1}{5}te^{3t}+\frac{27}{50}e^{-2t}-\frac{5}{6}.$$

*Note :*

- Your solution is not correct but fortunately, the problem does not seem to be in theory, perhaps is just some miscalculation, for example we can check that your solution does not work since if $t=0$ in your function $y(t)=\dfrac{82}{51}e^{3t}+\dfrac{79}{102}e^{-2t}+\dfrac1{17}te^{3t}+\dfrac5{6}$ you have $y(0)\not=0$ and it is a contradiction with the initial condition $y(0)=0$.

*PS :* For the partial fraction descomposition, consider that $\frac{3(2S-5)}{S(S-3)^{2}(S+2)}$ can be written as
$$\frac{3(2S-5)}{S(S-3)^{2}(S+2)}=\frac{A}{S-3}+\frac{B}{(S-3)^{2}}+\frac{C}{S}+\frac{D}{S+2}$$
Then, we can work with a bit of algebra and we get the linear system of equations
$$\begin{align} 
1\to\\S\to\\S^{2}\to\\S^{3}\to\\\end{align}\begin{pmatrix}0&0&18&0\\-6&2&-3&9\\-1&1&-4&-6\\1&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} A\\ B\\ C\\ D\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-15\\6\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
Solving the linear system of equations we have the solution
$$(A,B,C,D)=(22/75,1/5,-5/6,27/50)$$

Comment: can you tell me what you used on the rhs for A+B+C+D="the value here" for all 4 of them?

Comment: Of course, it's a pleasure to help. But can you tell me which part you mean? Are you referring to more detail on the decomposition into partial fractions? Or about more details on the inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: the decomposition into partial fraction part pls

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for the late reply. I added more details. I hope it is clear now.